# Split a title in half, or get as close to the middle as posible

Tags: php, javascript

So I have this H3 title and I want to take half of it and wrap it in a span.
The problem is the title can have 4 words, or 2 or 5 and so on, and I just can figure out how to split the title in half (more or less).

So I want to go from:

```
<h3>Some random title goes here</h3>
```

to this:

```
<h3>Some random <span class="green">title goes here</span></h3>
```

PHP or JavaScript, anything goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript you could use jQuery:

```
$('h3').each(function(i,el){
  el = $(el);
  var title = el.text().split(' ');
  el.html(
    title.splice(0, Math.floor(title.length/2)).join(' ')
      + ' <span>' + title.join(' ') + '</span>'
  );
});
```

This <strike>ought to work, haven't tested, though</strike> works.

Edit:
In the comments the problem came up, that if we only have one word, there still is a `<span></span>` at the end of `<h3>`. To prevent that, we could check for it beforehand:

```
$('h3').each(function(i,el){
  el = $(el);
  var title = el.text().split(' ');
  if(title.length === 1)
    return;
  el.html(
    title.splice(0, Math.floor(title.length/2)).join(' ')
      + ' <span>' + title.join(' ') + '</span>'
  );
});
```

Comment: i wil test this, sounds great as well ! .. anyway, the php and floor seems to work , this should too ! thanks a lot !

Comment: for some reason this does not fire ... but the general ideea is good

Comment: HAHA .. YEEEAH ! great man ! this is a lot better then the php code .. super duper ! thanks :)

Comment: Question : how can we skip the <span> adding if the title is only one word ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the title, get its length. Then, start searching from the half of the length for the next word boundary - usually this is a space character. Once you have that position, you know where to split.

```
$iSplit = strpos($title, ' ', strlen($title) / 2);
$sFirst = substr($title, 0, $iSplit);
$sSecond = substr($title, $iSplit + 1);
```

Or maybe have a look at [wordwrap()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php).

Comment: Unless you want to split in half by pixel size. The well known english proverb 'WWWWWWWWWW iiiiiiiiii' is probably the best example of this method failing horribly. With most other texts it will work fine, though. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol Why does it fail? I'd of course use a monospace font. :)

Comment: Yeah, I did too by marking that text as code. Had to modify my comment to prove my point. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how complex you want this to work. If you don't want it to split on words, are you satisfied with simply injecting the span's at the half way point of the title? Of course that would mean no considerations are made regarding injection at the start of the words.

Inject at character level:

```
<?php

$title = 'Some random title goes here';
$half_index = floor(strlen($title)/2);
$split_title = substr($title, 0, $half_index) . '<span class="green">' . substr($title, $half_index) . '</span>';

?>

<h3><?php echo $split_title ?></h3>
```

Inject at word level:

```
<?php

$title = 'Some random title goes here';
$words = preg_split('/ /', $title);
$half_index = floor(count($words)/2);
$split_title =
    implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $half_index)) . ' '.
    '<span class="green">' . implode(' ', array_slice($words, $half_index)) . '</span>';

?>

<h3><?php echo $split_title ?></h3>
```

Comment: probably other exemples work, but this is close to me.
thanks a lot man ! WORKS GREAT !

Answer (score 1):

Well this would work. But it is rather ugly.

```
var old = $('h3').text();
var words = old.split(' ');
var new_text = words[0] + ' ' + words[1] + ' ' + words[2];
var span_content =  ''; 
for(i = 3; i < words.length; i++){
    span_content += words[i] + ' '
}
span_content = span_content.trim();
new_text += '<span class="green">' + span_content + '</span>';
$('h3').html(new_text);
```

You can also do something similar in CSS if all you intend to do is hide the text. It is called `text-overflow: ellipsis`
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html

Answer (score 0):

Breaking it into words then inserting at roughly the middle could work:

```
<?PHP
$string = 'this is an odd string';
$insert = '<tag>';
$words = explode( ' ', $string );
$half = round( count( $words ) / 2 );
array_splice( $words, $half, 0, $insert );
print join( ' ', $words );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**How about this:**

```
$str = "Some random title goes here";
$format = "<h3>%s<span class='green'>%s</h3>";
vprintf($format, explode('&nbsp;', wordwrap($str, strlen($str)/2, '&nbsp;'), 2));
```

Using **[`wordwrap`](http://www.php.net/wordwrap)** allows you not to split in the middle of a word. You then use [**`explode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to only split the string into two chunks based on what `wordwrap` returned, and finally [**`vprintf`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vprintf.php) for the formatting.